# How to remove the grey background from canvases in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am making my first GUI just for fun, and was wondering if it's possible, and if so how to remove the greyish background from around my canvases. I am also aware the code is very messy; this is my first time doing anything with Tkinter.

Also just to clarify the project itself is 100% hypothetical and I have no intention whatsoever to use it for any malicious purposes.

```
  import tkinter as tk

    canvas_width = 400
    canvas_height = 20

    colours = ("#476042", "yellow")
    box=[]

    #---- Main Window ----
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Krypto Locker V1.0")
    window.geometry("400x400")
    window.resizable(width=True, height=True)



    #--- Background  -----

    C = tk.Canvas(window, bg="blue", height=250, width=300)
    filename = tk.PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\lauchlan\\Desktop\\Programing\\project\\resources\\image.png")
    background_label = tk.Label(window, image=filename)
    background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    C.pack()

    #---------------------




    #--- Functions  -----

    def countdown(count):
        # change text in label
        label['text'] = count

        if count > 0:
            # call countdown again after 1000ms (1s)
            window.after(1000, countdown, count-1)



    #--- Main Interface ----


    #-- Text Widget 1 --

    w = tk.Canvas(window,
               width=canvas_width,
               height=canvas_height)
    w.pack()

    w.create_text(canvas_width / 2,
                  canvas_height / 2,
                  text="Welcome to Krytpto Locker V1.0 ")
    w.place(x=10, y=20,)

    #-- Text Widget 2 --

    e = tk.Canvas(window,
               width=500,
               height=20)
    e.pack()

    e.create_text(canvas_width / 2,
                  canvas_height / 2,
                  text="All your personal files will soon be encrypted! ")
    e.place(x=10, y=40,)

    #-- Text Widget 3 --

    h = tk.Canvas(window,
               width=500,
               height=500)
    h.pack()

    h.create_text(   195 / 1,
                   40 / 1, text="‌‌ ‌‌ Hello, you're computer has been infected by Krypto Locker all your \npersonal files will soon be encrypted and deleted in order to prevent this \n‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ you will be required to send $300 to a secure bitcoin wallet\n ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ you will then recieve an email containing a recovery password")
    h.place(x=10, y=70,)





    #--- Countdown Timer -------------------------------------

    #-- Text  --

    m = tk.Canvas(window,
               width=500,
               height=500)
    m.pack()

    m.create_text(80 / 1,
                  50 / 1,
                  text="Time Until Files Encrypted : ")
    m.place(x=1, y=339,)


    #-- Timer  --

    label = tk.Label(window)
    label.place(x=155, y=380,)
    countdown(1000)

    #---------------------------------------------------------



    #--- Recovery Password Box -------------------------------------

    #---- Text ---
    l = tk.Canvas(window,
               width=500,
               height=100)
    l.pack()

    l.create_text(80 / 1,
                  50 / 1,
                  text="Enter Recovery Password : ")
    l.place(x=1, y=250,)

    #---- Entry Box ----


    password = tk.Entry(window)

    password.place(x=165, y=292)


    #---- Submit Button ----

    submit = tk.Button(window, text="Submit",)
    submit.place(x=300, y=289)



    #----------------------------------------------------------------




















    tk.mainloop()
```

[image: What the program looks like currently]

Comment: Do you intend to change the colour of the background? Or do you intend to make the background transparent in order to make the image visible?

Comment: i intend to make them transparent so you can see the image background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so, make one canvas with all the text. and add an image to the canva s before you add these. Worked or me.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to change the colour, just before the tk.mainloop:

```
h.config(background="snow")
l.config(background="snow")
m.config(background="snow")
e.config(background="snow")
w.config(background="snow")
C.config(background="snow")
```

You can't make the canvas transparent. Also, the better practice is to add the text and other widgets to the tkinter window (if you want the image to show maximum).